# Datatable to xml with different schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, ado.net

I need to convert my datatable data to this schema (To be opened in MS Excel).

#### Datatable Schema

```
ReferId    Name    Salary
2457165     ABC    10000
```

#### Output Schema Example

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <ss:Table>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell  ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">Refer_ID</Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell  ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell  ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">Salary</Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2457165</Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ABC</Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">10000</Data></ss:Cell>
   </ss:Row>
</ss:Table>
```

#### What I had tried

I tried to write simple xml with `DataTable.WriteXml()`

```
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
dt.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);
```

But schema is different. I tried some loop through rows and columns of datatable. But stuck in that, Any help will be appriciated

#### Update 1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

<Styles>
 <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
  <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  <Borders/>
  <Font/>
  <Interior/>
  <NumberFormat/>
  <Protection/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="s27">
  <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Bold="1"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="s21">
  <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\-mm\-dd"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="s22">
  <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\-mm\-dd\ hh:mm:ss"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="s23">
  <NumberFormat ss:Format="hh:mm:ss"/>
 </Style>
</Styles>
```

Comment: see if [Export DataSet to Multiple Excel Sheets](http://web4.codeproject.com/Articles/31516/Export-DataSet-to-Multiple-Excel-Sheets) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Refer_Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2457165, "ABC", 10000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2457166, "DEF", 20000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2457167, "GHI", 30000 });


            string header =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>" +
                "<Workbook" +
                "  xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\"" +
                "  xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"" +
                "  xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">" +
                "</Workbook>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement workbook = doc.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Workbook").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ssNs = workbook.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ss");
            XNamespace xNs = workbook.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("x");
            XNamespace defaultNs = workbook.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement styles = new XElement(defaultNs + "Styles", new object[] {
                new XElement(defaultNs + "Style", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "ID", "Default"),
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "Name", "Normal"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Alignment", new XAttribute(ssNs + "Vertical","Bottom")),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Borders"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Font"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Interior"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Numberformat"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Protection")
                }),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "Style", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "ID", "s27"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "Font", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute(xNs + "Family", "Swiss"),
                        new XAttribute(ssNs + "Color", "#0000FF"),
                        new XAttribute(ssNs + "Bold", 1)
                    }),
                }),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "Style", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "ID", "s21"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ssNs + "Format", "yyyy\\-mm\\-dd")),
                }),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "Style", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "ID", "s22"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ssNs + "Format", "yyyy\\-mm\\-dd\\ hh:mm:ss")),
                }),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "Style", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "ID", "s23"),
                    new XElement(defaultNs + "NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ssNs + "Format", "hh:mm:ss")),
                })
            });
            workbook.Add(styles);

            XElement table = new XElement(ssNs + "Table");
            workbook.Add(table);

            XElement newRow = new XElement(ssNs + "Row");
            table.Add(newRow);

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                newRow.Add(new XElement(ssNs + "Cell", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute(ssNs + "StyleID", "s27"),
                    new XElement(ssNs + "Data", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute(ssNs + "Type", "String"),
                        col.ColumnName
                    })
                }));
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {

                newRow = new XElement(ssNs + "Row");
                table.Add(newRow);
                string[] itemArray = row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
                foreach (string item in itemArray)
                {
                    newRow.Add(new XElement(ssNs + "Cell", new object[] {
                    new XElement(ssNs + "Data", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute(ssNs + "Type", "String"),
                        item
                        })
                    }));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng your code is working fine. But it seems i need some extra header properties. I had updated the question. please take a look.

Comment: Updated code.  Please double check to make sure I don't have any typos.

Comment: Thanks for update, but my xml file is missing <?xml version="1.0"?> and an empty namespance xmlns is added to style and worksheet every time !

Comment: The xml identification (first line) will not show up in VS.  Only when you save the file.  I fixed the empty namespace

Comment: I am downloading the file after creating. and xml identification missing from that.

Comment: I finally found root cause of issue.  Workspace was getting the namespace ss.  After closely looking at your xml for Workspace I realized the default namespace is usually last.  So I put the default namespace last and now everything works right.

Comment: The problem kept on moving to different parts of document.  Finally got it right.

Comment: Did you use doc.Save("filename") which should include the identification line?

Comment: Thanks for your help @jdweng I make it working after few changes,